# PHP Syntax error: There is 1 more opening parenthesis

Tags: php, syntax-error

I'm trying to make a 'sticky' form but keep getting syntax errors on the relatively simple code:

```
<input id="first-name" name="first-name" type="text" value="<?php if (isset $_POST ['first-name']) { print $_POST ['first-name']; } ?>" />
```

These are the errors:
There is 1 more opening parenthesis '(' than expected.
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in your code on line 1.

I've tried several variations but nothing fixes the problem. Can anyone see what's wrong?

Comment: I see too many questions like this. Take the time to learn how to [interpret errors and fix your code](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2013/05/fixing-php-errors/).

Comment: @JasonMcCreary good post, something like this should be required reading before posting a php question IMHO

Comment: @JasonMcCreary - Thanks for that. I am relatively new to this and sometime struggle to understand my mistakes. I'll study the content of this post and see if it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the parentheses for your `isset()` function call. `isset()` is a [language construct](http://www.phpknowhow.com/basics/language-constructs-vs-built-in-functions/) which are the only times you can avoid using parenthesis.

```
<?php if (isset $_POST ['first-name'])
```

should be:

```
<?php if (isset($_POST ['first-name']))
```

Comment: Thanks for the speedy replies! I've updated each line accordingly but now I get this error:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /tls-contact-form.php on line 28

Below is updated code:
    <input id="first-name" name="first-name" type="text" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['first-name'])) { print $_POST['first-name']; } ?>" />

Comment: You contradict the link that you posted. The link states that `isset` *is* a language construct.

Answer (score 1):

```
<input id="first-name" name="first-name" type="text" value="<?php if (isset($_POST ['first-name'])) { print $_POST ['first-name']; } ?>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

`isset()` is a function, and you've forgotten its `()`

```
if (isset($_POST['first-name'])) { ... }
         ^---here             ^---here
```

There should generally also not be any spaces between `$_POST` and its first `[`. It's not a syntax error, but it's also not good practice.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input id="first-name" name="first-name" type="text" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['first-name'])) { print $_POST ['first-name']; } ?>" />
```

isset is a function you need to use `()` for this function calling and you need to pass variable inside `()`